# Fedora Alternatives and Java: Switching JAVA_HOME At Same Time?

Tags: java, fedora

I have to switch between 3 separate JDKs and understand the concepts of the alternatives system.

However, when I switch from one to another, is there a way to automatically set JAVA_HOME to the new JDK?

Comment: Shouldn't JAVA_HOME point to the symlink, ergo always to the correct place?

Comment: Good point. The image on this box is pointing directly at the install directory though.

Comment: ...then change the JAVA_HOME once to point to the symlink.